# How to give the correct format to this JSON response in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rest, api

I'm trying to format a JSON response from the Spotify API, I tried several methods but none of them match the desired format, I appreciate your help since I'm new in RoR.

I tried using some methods like `pretty_generate()` and `neat_generate`, but I cannot figure out how to set the format correctly, also I'm using Spotify gem to fetch data from the API.

```rb
    render json: JSON.neat_generate(@artists.as_json)
```

this is the output I'm getting:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Metallica",
    "image":"{\"height\"=>640, \"url\"=>\"https://i.scdn.co/image/
     5a06711d7fc48d5e0e3f9a3274ffed3f0af1bd91\", \"width\"=>640}",
    "genres":"[\"alternative metal\", \"hard rock\", \"metal\", \"old school 
     thrash\", \"rock\", \"speed metal\", \"thrash metal\"]",
    "popularity":"86",
    "spotify_url":"spotify:artist:2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
    "spotify_id":"2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
   },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Diomedes Diaz",
    "image":"{\"height\"=>640, 
    \"url\"=>\"https://i.scdn.co/image/
    c3b77cdff8b152466447e4573c45613b06fbcf1b\", \"width\"=>640}",
    "genres":"[\"cumbia\", \"vallenato\"]",
    "popularity":"61",
    "spotify_url":"spotify:artist:66NweiA3nU84k1S3SZdTSG",
    "spotify_id":"66NweiA3nU84k1S3SZdTSG",
   },
]
```

But the expected output should be like this:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      name: "song One",
      spotify_url: 
      "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0O3xlhTJPTrGevY2FnYUQC",
      preview_url: "https://p.scdn.co/mp3- 
      preview/7a7becf24a93022ae9068ac3cb2e88e61563e268",
      duration_ms: 9870,
      explicit: true
    },
    {
      name: "song Two",
      spotify_url: 
      "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0O3xlhTJPTrGevY2FnYUQC",
      preview_url: "https://p.scdn.co/mp3- 
      preview/7a7becf24a93022ae9068ac3cb2e88e61563e268",
      duration_ms: 9870,
      explicit: true    
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That ("the expected output") is not JSON. That looks like JavaScript source code. There is a difference. It also seems to contain fields that do not exist in your data (like `duration_ms`) - no amount of formatting tricks can pull that rabbit out of a hat. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); why, exactly, do you desire this format?

Comment: Amadan has a point: it looks like the data you are getting has already been deserialized.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to render, not the deserialized format but the Javascript format-like, with keys without double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is the right way to do this and the let's get it to work way. Let's do the latter because its easier for a junior to understand:

## Quick Way

The below is sudo code. You will have to fix it.

```
artists = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Metallica",
    "image":"{\"height\"=>640, \"url\"=>\"https://i.scdn.co/image/
     5a06711d7fc48d5e0e3f9a3274ffed3f0af1bd91\", \"width\"=>640}",
    "genres":"[\"alternative metal\", \"hard rock\", \"metal\", \"old school 
     thrash\", \"rock\", \"speed metal\", \"thrash metal\"]",
    "popularity":"86",
    "spotify_url":"spotify:artist:2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
    "spotify_id":"2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
    "created_at":"2019-06-23T17:27:11.893Z",
    "updated_at":"2019-06-23T17:27:11.893Z"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Diomedes Diaz",
    "image":"{\"height\"=>640, 
    \"url\"=>\"https://i.scdn.co/image/
    c3b77cdff8b152466447e4573c45613b06fbcf1b\", \"width\"=>640}",
    "genres":"[\"cumbia\", \"vallenato\"]",
    "popularity":"61",
    "spotify_url":"spotify:artist:66NweiA3nU84k1S3SZdTSG",
    "spotify_id":"66NweiA3nU84k1S3SZdTSG",
    "created_at":"2019-06-23T17:27:12.024Z",
    "updated_at":"2019-06-23T17:27:12.024Z"
  },
]

array = artists.map do |artist|
  {
    name: artist['name'],
    spotify_url: artist['spotify_url'],
    # The below attributes I dont know how to get because they're not in the response
    # preview_url: "https://p.scdn.co/mp3- 
    # preview/7a7becf24a93022ae9068ac3cb2e88e61563e268",
    # duration_ms: 9870,
    # explicit: true
  }
end
```

Then do this

```
render json: { data: array }
```

## Another Option

I find the architecture a little weird. I'm assuming you have a backend and frontend type architecture. Why not just return exactly what Spotify gives you to the frontend. Then have the front end use attributes it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch data in an object and use the to_json method.

Example :

```
puts student.to_json
```